# Problems setting the Default Schema

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In college I run the following command to alter my default schema:

```
ALTER USER [campus\s00103417]
WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = MyCmdSet01;
```

I recently installed SQL Server on my laptop under win7. Everything else works great. But when I create a database, then create a schema and try to set it as the default it gives me an error. Following is the code I run on my laptop.

```
ALTER USER [L01\Admin]
WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo;
```

Below is the error I am getting

```
Cannot alter the user 'L01\Admin', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

What I dont understand is, obviously I exist, I created the database. Also I taught I as the DBO would have permission to do pretty much anything I liked. Obviously I dont fully understand this stuff. Can anyone explain how I can the the command above to work so I can alter my default schema.

If it is relevant, I have only one windows login (no password). As soon as the computer boots, it pops me onto the desktop. Then I start up SQL Server 2008 Management Studio which asks me to connect and I type L01 as the server name and select windows authentication.

Any help would be greatly appreicated.

EDIT: I dont know if these will provide any help. I ran the commands:

```
SELECT SUSER_NAME()  --Output L01\Admin
SELECT USER_NAME()   --Output dbo
```

Answer (score 5):

You are talking about your login (I'm guess it is 'L01\Admin').  That is different than a database user.  If your login is in the `sysadmin` fixed server role, you are automatically mapped to the `dbo` built-in database user.  Therefore, that is why you aren't finding your `L01\Admin` user, because it actually doesn't exist.

Does that make sense?  Just remember:  `server login <> database user`.

Comment: I looked under security\logins and there I am. L01\Admin. So now that I know this is a login and not a database user. What do I need to change in order to make the command work as it does in college. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @FrancisRodgers you can create a separate database user and map your login to that database user instead of the `dbo` user.  Then you can modify the `default_schema` for that new database user that you are mapped to.

Comment: I tried creating a user MyXyz. It prompts me for a login name. When I enter L01\Admin it gives me the error ==> The login already has an account under a different user name. Error 15063). So I cant even create a user. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I was looking around for an unmap command. But I cant find out how to do it. Is there any chance you might describe the steps.

Comment: @FrancisRodgers Go into Security -> Logins.  Right-click your login name.  On the left, go to "User Mapping".  Then take of "dbo" where your user is mapped for that database.  Then create your new database user in your database with login as your login.

Comment: I get one of 3 errors. When I remove dbo from the User column and leave it blank I get error number 1038 (change alias to valid name). When I put in L01\Admin I get error number 15150 (cannot alter user dbo). So I put it back to dbo and modified the Default Schema Column. If left blank it succeeds but when reopened its back at dbo. When I pick another schema (ie guest) I get error number 15150 again. Any ideas what is going wrong here. Thanks again for all your help. If we get the answer I will bump up all your comments too for extra marks.

Comment: @FrancisRodgers what is your database **user** name?  Set that as the mapped username in your **login** settings for "User Mapping".

Comment: My db user name is dbo. The mapped username in the login for L01\Admin is allready set to this. When I try to change it. I get the errors mentioned. Its a bit like the song "Theres a hole in my bucket" :->

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server the user is a database level object. What is your current database when you execute the alter command? Do you actually have user called [L01\Admin]?

Comment: The previous answer showed me that a login is different than a user. When I look under S00103417\Security\Users (that is - DatabaseName\Security\Users) I the only users I see are dbo, guest, INFORMATION_SCHEMA, sys. I dont see anything for L01\Admin so I guess either I am the user dbo or one of the others. So what should I do to make my command work like it does in the college. Thanks for your answer.